# Is there a way to have a Hibernate mapping to a column that may or may not exist?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have a situation where a column on a table may or may not exist. Long story short, we have an optional feature that, if implemented, will tack on a column to a table. If a client chooses not to have the feature, they will not have the column.

I am trying to define a property in my DAO for it, in hopes of Hibernate not blowing up if the column is not there. Perhaps by setting the value to `null`. But, Hibernate is throwing an "invalid identifier" exception.

Does anyone know if you can do this? Have a column mapping that if the column is there Hibernate populates it but if it's not present, all is well and it's just `null`?

Many thanks.

Comment: Why not always have the column and have a value in another column that indicates the presence of the feature?

Comment: I am definitely barking up that tree. It seems a bit bizarre but those are the cards we were dealt.  I was hoping for some hibernate "flexibility" as a fall back.

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious option is to create different mappings and choose one of them during startup depending on the environment.

Depending on the way you configure Hibernate you can use some options to avoid duplication between different mappings:

- if you use `.hbm.xml`, you can apply some preprocessing to it
- if you use annotations, you can override them using config files in `orm.xml` syntax

Comment: Thanks for the feedback...I think I am going down the path of forcing the addition of the column. Seems to messy otherwise.  Thanks again for the help.